# Conditions in Excel for calculations?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I currently have the following dataset:

[image: Dataset Image below]

What i would like to calculate is the following:

How can i find a way of extracting the number of times a company has only used 1 product, 2products, 3 products etc

The values in the rows are just the counts (so the amount of times a company used that product e.g. 1 means they used product once, twice means product 2 times etc)

So in the dataset image example

Company 1 has only used 1 product, i would like to apply this to the entire dataset, where only 1 product has been used. This is the same for company 2 as only 1 product was used but 3 times, so an output would say something like "2" - which corresponds to the amount of companies that have only used 1 product

And for example where there is more than one product used such as company 3, i would like to have it read "3" the amount of companies that used 3 products

etc

Any ideas

Please see my propsed outcome below:

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add a new column `PRODUCT_COUNT` with the following formula, and drag down.

`=COUNTIF(B2:I2,”>0”)` to count the number of products utilized by each company more than zero times.

In your example you have 7 companies. So in your summary table, you could do another `COUNTIF` like so:

- `=COUNTIF($H$2:$H$8,1)`
  to count how many companies used exactly 1 product.
- `=COUNTIF($H$2:$H$8,2)` to count how many companies used exactly 2 products.
- `=COUNTIF($H$2:$H$8,”>=3”)` to count how many companies used 3 or more products.

If the number of companies changes, you would need to adjust the size of the range. A named range in the `PRODUCT_COUNT` column may be a good idea.

```
=COUNTIF(PRODUCT_COUNT,”>=3”)
```